# Normed space and absolute value

Tags: normed-spaces, absolute-value

For a general normed space $(V,\|{\cdot}\|)$ suppose that the vector space $V$ is over some field $K$ that is not $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb Z_p$ or any of it expansions, then, in general, how we define the absolute value such that

$$\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|$$

where $\alpha\in K$? I suppose we will need to define some function of the kind

$$|{\cdot}|:K\to\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$$

I searched some information about the general topic of normed spaces but I dont found something about this, can you give me some text, link, bibliography or just enlighten this question? Thank you.

Comment: For information about normed spaces over arbitrary fields and some introductory references see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2568042/113061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute value is a notion related to [vector lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space) (which has nothing to do with the notion of norm). Indeed, given a vector space $X$ with a partial order $\le$ such that finite suprema (and infima) exist, then the absolute value is defined by
$$
|x|:=\sup\{x,-x\}.
$$
for each $x \in X$. For a standard textbook, you can see [Positive Operators](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781402050077).

Comment: If I understand correctly you mean here that $X$ is at the same time the vector space and the field, right?

Comment: The definition of absolute value works for vector lattices; in your case, you need a partial order on the field for which finite suprema and infima exist (it can be shown that this is equivalent to the existence of the absolute value itself)